# Alternative working method to the wrong one which uses curl handles in multithreading

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, httprequest, libcurl

Since libcurl is thread-safe, as stated from its official [documentation](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/threadsafe.html):

> libcurl is thread safe but ...

which also says:

> Handles. You must never share the same handle in multiple threads. You can pass the handles around among threads, but you must never use a single handle from more than one thread at any given time.

and so creating single handles on multiple threads and make them (handles) synchronized wouldn't work.

How can I get so an alternative, efficient and cheap way of making HTTP requests (generally, and so POST and GET requests too)?

Comment: _"and so creating single handles on multiple threads and make them (handles) synchronized wouldn't work."_ How you're interpreting this? I'd read it that synchronizing usage of handles with a mutex or alike should work fine.

Comment: I don't know which source you're referring. Generally `std::mutex` and OpenSSL connections aren't really directly related.

Answer (score 2):

At least to me, it sounds like you're mis-interpreting the documents.

You can create a separate handle in each thread that needs to make requests, and that thread can make requests via that handle (safely).

You can create one handle, and share it between multiple threads, but you need to synchronize access, so only one of those threads is making a request at any given time. The obvious way to accomplish that would be to protect the handle with a mutex, which needs to be acquired before a call is made, and is held until the call completes.

For the sake of simplicity, you probably want to create a separate handle in each thread that's going to make curl calls. At least as I read the documentation, as long as each thread uses a separate handle that's can't/won't be used by another thread concurrently, you're safe.

Comment: Shouldn't it be _as long as each thread uses a separate handle that **can** / **will** be used by another thread concurrently_?

Comment: @cpp2alker: Can? No--the whole point is that each thread creates its own handle. No other thread uses that handle. Then the thread can just make calls, with no synchronization (etc.) required. If the handle is shared by another thread, then you need to synchronize access to the handle, which will add difficulty.

Comment: Thank you for this good explanation. Could you make an example-suggestion of using std::mutex to _synchronize access to the handle_? Yes, I'm going to use an handle which is shared from multiple threads.